# How do mahout refresh from database?

Tags: mahout

I'm new using mahout. I would like to know how do mahout refresh the data from database, I mean, I don't know if the refresh function do a "select .. from taste_preference" or if it do some kind of special select over the data so that the information is not selected completely again because this last method is not very scalable. I'm using a ReloadFromJDBCDataModel implementation (DataModel), a GenericItemSimilarity implementation(itemSimilarity) and a GenericItemBasedRecommender (Recommender). Somebody can help me I or tell me where to find this info?. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The SQL statements live in subclasses like `MySQLJDBCDataModel`. A refresh does involve selecting the whole table again as it needs to re-load all the data. You should just look in the source code to see what it does.